# two forms in the same page

Tags: forms

I tried some things without success. I tried to make two forms in the same HTML page.One after another or even better in parallel (one in the left and other in the right). The page at first contains data that are loaded to it. After I have the two forms which user can enter data and submit. Those data pass to a JavaScript functions.

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly isnt working?

Comment: You don't switch your `<div id="content" style="display: none;">` to display `block` somewhere after loading, or some code is missing. Try to add something like `window.addEventListener("load", () => { document.getElementById("content").display = "block"); });`

Answer (score 2):

please remove  `style="display: none;"`

Comment: yes but then it shows the column names, think if the blockchain is empty?